# What is the convention for main function return values in C++?

Tags: c++

I was reading sample code and found that for error messages they used `return -1;` and for the main function they used `return 0;`. However, when I substituted the main function return value to `return 10000;`, it still built and run with no errors. Does this mean that return values can be arbitrarily chosen and has no meaning for the computer (Excluding the case where you are using the return value for some user-defined operation)? What is the usual convention in assigning return values for different cases?

Comment: The return value of `main` indicates something to the operating system. So `main` is different to other functions. You can do anything you like with other functions. Can you clarify that you are just asking about `main`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The return value from a main function (the application) can be used in other applications to indicate that how the program is terminated. Traditionally `0` is used if the program terminated successfully and other integers (`negative or positive`) indicates there were some problems or other conditions.

These are different from application to application and you can find these on their manuals to find what each return value means.

For example you can see `grep` command manual (http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) it states that exit value `0` is if a line has selected, `1` means no line has selected and `2` means there was an error

Answer (score 1):

On systems that use `libc`, which is pretty much the majority of Unix systems, the following things happens when a program exits:

1. Functions registered with `atexit` or `on_exit` are called in reverse order
2. All open streams are closed, writing out any buffered output data
3. `_exit` is called, terminating the program

Only the low-order 8 bits of the exit status are kept, which truncates it to a value between `0` and `255`. How the return status is treated depends on the parent process. For example, if the parent process was Bash, values between `0` and `127` are user-defined values, while `128+` are treated specially.

Answer (score 1):

By convention a return value of 0 in **main** is often hint for the OS and users that the program was executed successfully. Other values can be used to represent different error codes or different paths of successful execution **specific to the program**. You can choose them freely.

For **other functions** in a program the interpretation of return values is up to the developer.

Answer (score 1):

The portable return values are `EXIT_SUCCESS`, `EXIT_FAILURE`, and `0` (which returns the same value as `EXIT_SUCCESS`. Those manifest contacts are defined in <cstdlib>. The meanings of any other values are system-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Returned value is specified by function definition:

```
ret function(params);
```

Then, any value of type `ret` will be accepted by the compiler.

Example:

```
int main();
```

Can return any value of type `int` (between `-INT_MAX` and `+INT_MAX`). Values outside this range can be automatically casted by the compiler. However, non `int` values (`return std::vector<int>()` for example) will lead to compiler errors.

Specifically, for the `main` function, you can return any value. Convention is to return 0 when no error occured, anything else when an error occured. Error values can be positive or negative, as you want.